# Prevent unmounting when navigating from screen B to A

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

So my issue: When using React Navigation, when user navigates to Screen A, A is mounted. When user goes to Screen B, B is mounted, A stays mounted. When user navigates back to A, B becomes unmounted but A stays mounted.

This is expected, [according to the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-lifecycle.html#docsNav).

I want B to stay mounted. Is this possible? If yes, then how?

```
const ThisStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    A: {
      screen: ScreenA,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: <HamburgerMenuButton navigation={navigation} />,
      }),
    },
    B: {
      screen: ScreenB,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'FOO',
    headerMode: 'screen',
    defaultNavigationOptions: navigationOptions,
  }
);
```

Why do I want this to be mounted?

Well I have to be using a package called [Reactive](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/tree/dev/packages/native). Reactive has a base component named [`<ReactiveComponent />`](https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivesearch/blob/dev/packages/native/src/components/basic/ReactiveComponent.js) which, when unmounted, invokes a `removeComponent` function which I'm trying to prevent from happening.

It seems that Reactive wasn't created to be used in different screens, but to achieve what I'm trying to complete, I need it to be used in this way.

Comment: Were you able to find solution for this @Dres ?

Comment: I did! I used the 'react-native-drawer' package and set the drawer to open from the right side. It gave me a similar screen nav animation, it acts like a screen if you set the offset to 0, and it doesn't unmount!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy. You're currently using `StackNavigation`, which works by mounting screens on top of each other and unmounting them when they're no longer needed. On the other hand, there are many other navigation options you can choose from if you simply want to navigate between different screens without unmounting them. For example, `TabNavigation`, `DrawerNavigation` `SwitchNavigator`,etc. Or you can even build your own `navigator` with `react-navigation`.

Here I use `switchNavigator`, which is often used for authentication flow, ie, logging the user in or logging the user out.

```
const ThisStack = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    A: {
      screen: ScreenA,
      navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: <HamburgerMenuButton navigation={navigation} />,
      }),
    },
    B: {
      screen: ScreenB,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'FOO',
    headerMode: 'screen',
    defaultNavigationOptions: navigationOptions,
  }
);
```

All I've done is simply use `createSwitchNavigator` instead of `createStackNavigator`. Let me know if this works for you

Comment: Is there any way to do this in React Navigation 5, where we don't have SwitchNavigator?